# How to convert (Object obj) this type of object to JSON and then back?

Tags: java, android, json, object, gson

I tried this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
            Log.e("TAGS", "Known Face extra obj: " + rec.getExtra());
            Log.e("TAGS", "Known Face extra JSON: " + gson.toJson(rec.getExtra()));
            Object obj = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(rec.getExtra()), Object.class);
            Log.e("TAGS", "Known Face extra from JSON: " + obj);
```

The response what I get is:

Known Face extra obj: [[F@1f4af8f

Known Face extra JSON: [[0.0010238411,-0.004055016]]

Known Face extra from JSON: [[0.0010238411, -0.004055016]]

I'm not sure why it is not converting back to the Object that I need!

Comment: What is the type of `rec.getExtra()`?

Comment: It is of Object type

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to specify the type in fromJson like

```
Object obj = gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(rec), double[][].class);
```